# How can I show the code of my program in the output in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner python coder and I am currently using eclipse IDE to code.I want to display the code of my program in my program itself. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: You have to be more specific. Do you want to write a program that displays its own code?

Comment: Can you please share you code, and let us know what output you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I want to write a program that displays its own code.

Comment: You can simply read the file in which your code is written and display it.

Comment: @AyaanSinghSaundh Still confused, what exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, use this. This will read the file and display it's contents

```
print(open(__file__).read())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python string escaping, string literal generation & unescaping. Paste your own code in here:
https://www.pythonescaper.com/

And you can print escaped string;

```
print("Past here escaped string")
```